# have javascript trigger on onchange and on load

Tags: javascript, onchange, onload

I have a javascript which currently gets called using the 'onchange' event.

```
<SELECT NAME="person<?PHP echo $i; ?>" id="person<?PHP echo $i; ?>" onchange="get(<? echo $i; ?>);">
```

This select input replies on me having chosen a selection from the drop down list. if the page is loaded and the select has a 'selected' attribute so that a selection is preloaded, the javascript is not called. How can I change this so that the script will be called on load for the existing selection and on change should the user change the option?

this does not work:

```
<SELECT NAME="person<?PHP echo $i; ?>" id="person<?PHP echo $i; ?>" onchange="get(<? echo $i; ?>);" onload="get(<? echo $i; ?>);">
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: onload event doesn't work for select tag. . You should try working on  the values on docuement ready state and place it back to select tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<SELECT NAME="person<?PHP echo $i; ?>" id="person<?PHP echo $i; ?>" onchange="get(<? echo $i; ?>);">
```

select does not have onload event. you can call onload function on body tag,

```
<body onload="get(<? echo $i; ?>);">
```

But for this function to work ***$i*** should be defined before body tag ,otherwise it will return a undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because SELECT doesnot have onload event. Use it in windows onload instead. BTW where $i comes from

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    get(<? echo $i; ?>);

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have used jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

 $('select').each(function() { 
         $(this).change(function(){
             myFunction();
       });
     });

 myFunction();

});
```